# Inner product space and orthogonality proof.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Why does this automatically mean that the sets are orthogonal? I am a little confused about this? How would I necessarily prove also?

Comment: What are $W_1$  and $W_2$?

Comment: the set of odd and even polynomials

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You want to prove that given two functions: $f_1$ and $f_2$, being one even and the other odd, then $\langle f_1, f_2 \rangle = 0$. However, the product of an even function with an odd function results in an odd function (proof?), and the integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval, such as $[-1,1]$ is zero (proof?). This proves that the sets are orthogonal because the functions we took were arbitrary.

Comment: It only proves each is contained in the orthogonal of the other.